# MSSQL print a message for XML

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery, mssql-jdbc

I try to check my data bad if a table is existing and get the print output from my statement as XML

For that I tried following code:

```
IF (
    EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
            WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
            AND TABLE_NAME = 'TABLE_NAME_I'
    )
) BEGIN
    PRINT 'Table allready exists in database'
    FOR XML AUTO
END;
```

But the only thing I gat is:

```
Database operation failed: Incorrect syntax near the FOR keyword.
```

I also tried to set the `FOR XML AUTO` in front of `PRINT 'Table allready exists in database'` but the resault is the same.

I'm using an JDBC Connector to realize the connection and the output.

Is my project possible at all or do I have to combine it with something else to achieve this?

Thanks in advance for the help.

UPDATE

---

I also tried now

```
SET @string = '<MESSAGE>Table allready exists in database</MESSAGE>';
SET @xml = CONVERT(XML, @string);
SELECT @xml;
```

Here is my output which I get:

```
<Data>
   <object_II>
      <_1/>
   </object_II>
<Data>
```

Expected output:

```
<Data>
   <object_II>
      <MESSAGE>Table allready exists in database</MESSAGE>
   </object_II>
<Data>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try XQuery and FLWOR expression to compose desired XML.

> SQL

```
DECLARE @message VARCHAR(100) = 'Table allready exists in database';

SELECT CAST(N'' AS XML).query('
<Data>
   <object_II>
      <MESSAGE>{sql:variable("@message")}</MESSAGE>
   </object_II>
</Data>
');
```

Or completely dynamic XML composition:

```
SELECT CAST(N'' AS XML).query('
    element  Data {
        element  object_II {
            element  MESSAGE {
                text {sql:variable("@message")}
            }
        }
    }
');
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need SELECT, not a PRINT:

```
SELECT 'Table already exists' as Message
FOR XML PATH('object_II'), ROOT ('Data');
```

Comment: My JDBC puts out: `<Data> <object_II> <XML_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B>&lt;Data&gt;&lt;row&gt;&lt;object_II&gt;&lt;Message&gt;Table already exists&lt;/Message&gt;&lt;/object_II&gt;&lt;/row&gt;&lt;/Data&gt;</XML_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B> </object_II> </Data>` Dosn't looks like I want but works in a different way :)

Comment: Wouter, please connect with me on LinkedIn.